# How do I fill out a W9?

Tags: united-states, irs, ssn

On a W9 which line denotes whom the check is payable to, line 1 or 2?

If a company is an individual/sole proprietor, and line 1 and 2 is filled in which line do I use for the remit to?

Answer (score 1):

If they are a single-member LLC and filled in line 2 with their business name, then I would use that. Either would technically work since their personal name should be on the business' account.

Answer (score 0):

Line 1 should be your name as it appears on your tax return; line 2 would be the business name. From the [IRS instructions for W-9](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf):

> **Specific Instructions**
>
> **Line 1**
> You must enter one of the following on
> this line; do not leave this line blank. The name should match the
> name on your tax return. If this Form W-9 is for a joint account
> (other than an account maintained by a foreign financial institution
> (FFI)), list first, and then circle, the name of the person or entity
> whose number you entered in Part I of Form W-9. If you are providing
> Form W-9 to an FFI to document a joint account, each holder of the
> account that is a U.S. person must provide a Form W-9. a. Individual.
> Generally, enter the name shown on your tax return. If you have
> changed your last name without informing the Social Security
> Administration (SSA) of the name change, enter your first name, the
> last name as shown on your social security card, and your new last
> name. Note: ITIN applicant: Enter your individual name as it was
> entered on your Form W-7 application, line 1a. This should also be the
> same as the name you entered on the Form 1040/1040A/1040EZ you filed
> with your application. b. Sole proprietor or single-member LLC. Enter
> your individual name as shown on your 1040/1040A/1040EZ on line 1. You
> may enter your business, trade, or “doing business as” (DBA) name on
> line 2. c. Partnership, LLC that is not a single-member LLC, C
> corporation, or S corporation. Enter the entity's name as shown on the
> entity's tax return on line 1 and any business, trade, or DBA name on
> line 2. d. Other entities. Enter your name as shown on required U.S.
> federal tax documents on line 1. This name should match the name shown
> on the charter or other legal document creating the entity. You may
> enter any business, trade, or DBA name on line 2. e. Disregarded
> entity. For U.S. federal tax purposes, an entity that is disregarded
> as an entity separate from its owner is treated as a “disregarded
> entity.” See Regulations section 301.7701-2(c)(2)(iii). Enter the
> owner's name on line 1. The name of the entity entered on line 1
> should never be a disregarded entity. The name on line 1 should be the
> name shown on the income tax return on which the income should be
> reported. For example, if a foreign LLC that is treated as a
> disregarded entity for U.S. federal tax purposes has a single owner
> that is a U.S. person, the U.S. owner's name is required to be
> provided on line 1. If the direct owner of the entity is also a
> disregarded entity, enter the first owner that is not disregarded for
> federal tax purposes. Enter the disregarded entity's name on line 2,
> “Business name/disregarded entity name.” If the owner of the
> disregarded entity is a foreign person, the owner must complete an
> appropriate Form W-8 instead of a Form W-9. This is the case even if
> the foreign person has a U.S. TIN.
>
> **Line 2**
> If you have a business name,
> trade name, DBA name, or disregarded entity name, you may enter it on
> line 2.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. That's not what the W9 is for.

While it's probably almost always true that they will have a bank account with a name similar to their "doing business as" name on line 2, the bank may have set it up differently, or they may have changed one and not the other.